# group by having max

Tags: mysql

Хочу получить максимальное значение `top` для текущего дня недели.

```
        select `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name`,    
        sum(case `order`.order_status when 'fake' then 1 else 0 end) as total,
        max(deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale) as top
        FROM `delivery-types`
        LEFT JOIN deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo
        on `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name` = delivery_first_week_repo.type
        INNER JOIN order_delivery ON `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_code` = order_delivery.order_delivery_code
        INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery.order_id = `order`.order_id
        where delivery_first_week_repo.week_day = DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE())
        and order_delivery_code in('cream-ec','courier')
        and order_createdAt >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (7 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
        and order_createdAt <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (0 + (5 + DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)) % 7) DAY
        GROUP BY deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale
        having max(deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo.from_sale)
```

Но выводит несколько значений [image: result]

Comment: Добавил подзапрос в условия `and from_sale = (select max(from_sale) from deliverability.delivery_first_week_repo)` выдает пустой результат

Comment: Тогда уж лучше добавить `ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT 1`... а чтобы понять, в чём дело - надо добавить в список полей вывода выражение группировки.